# Why css not working on ion-header, ion-toolbar and ion-icon?

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm create Ionic 4 angular app, and used css styles on ion-header, ion-toolbar and ion-icon. but css not work as expected ?

[Here is my stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-updnzj)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ts file

you have not include styleUrls, thus styles are not being applied

please add:

```
styleUrls: ['/home.css']
```

your config will look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.css']
})
```

Comment: as your solution working , but something not work as expected.i have update my stackblitz code see above.

Comment: Actually your styles are working, but they are getting overridden by the css classes appended by the iconic framework.

Comment: You can check that by using the inspect element. Since frameworks are know to append their theme classes to the components. You can refer to the documentation of the iconic for more clarification, like they use custom css properties as well, like [style.--background='color']

Answer (score 0):

Use style url properly as 
          styleUrls: ['/home.css'],
  Your are overriding the build in functionality of ionic and no link of that style file in template