# How to change the color of the ion icon without any inline css?

Tags: css, icons

i want to change the color to white .I tried using color:light as well but it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
    <style>
        ion-icon {
  color:blue;
}
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Shivam welcome at SO, nothing could be easier, do some reading: [w3schools: CSS color Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Please point out the error as well. I didn't find anything relevant there.Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574419/why-css-not-working-on-ion-header-ion-toolbar-and-ion-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS 101: if you want a color to be white, set it `White`, or any color for that matter either one of the [w3schools: CSS colors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) or use hex: `color: #xxxxxx` (White = #ffffff) or something like `color: rgba(r,g,b,a)` (White: rgba(255,255,255,1) use 'a' for alpha value).

Again: [w3schools: CSS color Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp) with the relevant info.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
  <style>
    ion-icon {
      color: White;
      background-color: Black;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```